# How to use Mediatr with masstransit?

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, masstransit, mediatr

I have implemented rabbitmq using masstransit. But my project is build using clean architecture and i am using mediatr here. So how can i call my handlers from masstransit class.

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://youtu.be/YpBvka-xwBM) - since it's using clean architecture.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally You can migrate from mediator to MassTransit because MassTransit consumers are equal to mediator command handlers.
watch this video for detail migration process.

```
<a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97PXJIrGnes />
```

you can create mediator command in MassTransit consumers also